# Flexbox in Bootstrap 4 acting weird

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm trying to use flexbox to align vertically a section.

So this is what I'm trying to align vertically:

[image: Screenshot of web page. Below the menubar is the page title and a search section that has a background image behind it. Below it is a lot of white space before you get to three columns containing list items.]

HTML:

```
<!--Top Hero Section -->
    <div class="d-flex hm-hero justify-content-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-end">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h1 class="text-center">Fix Your Problem Today!</h1>
                    <p class="text-center">Start searching for a contractor or company around your area and get your problem fixed in a matter of hours!</p>
                </div>

                <!--Form Section -->
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="e.g. plumbing, carpentry" id="example-text-input">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="e.g. city name, postcode" id="example-text-input">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Regarding CSS, I've only applied this:

```
.hm-hero {
    background: url("../img/main_pic.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: fill;
    min-height: 600px;
}
```

I can't figure out why flexbox is not working. I've tried two classes, align-content/items-center in whatever div possible and still can't get it to work.

So since I have that full width div with the background image, inside it is a container div, which I'm trying to get it to stay vertically. I really want to avoid putting a 200px margin top to this.  Is this is a Bootstrap 4 bug?

Comment: What elements do you want to align? How (top, center, bottom...)?

Comment: The entire "fix your problem today with the input forms together, aligned vertically to the 600px container I set. Now I also see things are not aligned horizontally also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the `align-items-center` class to the flex div parent and it worked. As long as you have a height on the .hm-hero the content will be centered. Hope this helps. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4jne5qxq/)

```css
.hm-hero {
    background: url("https://placehold.it/960x600") no-repeat;
    background-size: fill;
    min-height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--Top Hero Section -->
    <div class="d-flex hm-hero justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-end">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h1 class="text-center">Fix Your Problem Today!</h1>
                    <p class="text-center">Start searching for a contractor or company around your area and get your problem fixed in a matter of hours!</p>
                </div>

                <!--Form Section -->
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="e.g. plumbing, carpentry" id="example-text-input">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="e.g. city name, postcode" id="example-text-input">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```